# Can many ajax requests wrongly affect my variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, loops

I'm currently working on a script in JavaScript / jQuery to calculate statistics.
So it asked to do a lot of HTTP requests, parse DOM and modify variables values. I met some errors and I fear it is the fact that the AJAX requests are asynchronous that is the cause.

For example, suppose I want to browse a lot of questions on StackOverflow, and evaluate how many times a member appears.

I will code something like this:

```
var users = {};
var checked_pages = 0;

function get_users(num_question) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/" + parseInt(num_question), // I Know that sometimes, the question is removed or the url redirects to an answer, but it does not matter, it is not the issue.
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            var users_in_page = $(".user-details > a").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get(); // Users who appear in the page.
            for (var i = 0; i < users_in_page.length; i++) {
                if (isNaN(users[users_in_page[i]])) { // The user is not yet in the dictionnary.
                    users[users_in_page[i]] = 1;
                } else {
                    users[users_in_page[i]] += 1;
                }
            }

            checked_pages += 1;

            if (checked_pages == 99) { // Every requests are made.
                alert("END");
                // Do something with my dictionary.
            }
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    get_users(i);
}
```

My fear is that since all requests are made very quickly and at the same time, counting errors can slip and result in a distorted final dictionary variable.

That is why before that I used a callback in my function, which replaced my final loop and allowed to be sure that everything was properly conducted. But of course, it is much slower.

```
function get_users(num_question) {
    ...

    num_question += 1;
    get_users(num_question);
}

get_users(1);
```

Can my first proposal, with AJAX requests at the same time, cause problems so that I fear?
Because I have already created a script like this and the results are weird, and I wonder if it comes from there...
If this is indeed the case, would not there is a way to ensure the integrity of my variables and my dictionary while increasing requests faster than my second function?

Comment: don't see whay should be any problems, `get_users` creates a closure and since `num_question` is passed as a param, can only have value of instance of the closure. Success callback can only fire for url that uses specific url with `num_question` in it

Comment: I'm talking about first....give example of problems you see

Comment: if browser getting hit with too many requests ( not sure what limits are or if is a problem even)...could add a small delay with setTimeout wrapping $.ajax

Comment: You're evil! Take a look at what happened to me when I tried to run your script in jsfiddle: http://d.pr/i/yKBg+ haha

Comment: Certainly this is not a browser limitation. Although browsers have a limit of concurrent requests to the same domain, the surplus ones will be queued to be requested later. I'd probably stick with some solution that limits the number of requests per second to avoid being blocked by the server and add a fallback in case some request failed due to it.

Comment: @Guilherme Yeah, sorry, I had the same problem when I tested it...

Comment: But check this GreaseMonley script : http://pastebin.com/WZFdDm9Q It works on a french website (sorry) : http://m.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-47-46404-1-0-1-0-printf-blabla.htm My script returns 9, but they are many more than 9 users in the first 50 pages...

Comment: You script is not working probably due to the Stack Overflow server DOS protection. I saw a lot of cancelled requests in the network tab of my browser when I ran it.

Comment: @Guilherme If you are talking about the pastebin script, I am sorry, I made a mistake with the \@include. Here is the working script (I use GreaseMonkey): http://pastebin.com/Rh30JZsh

Comment: Well, onnce again I made a big mistake, it should be 
'var users_in_page = $("a.pseudo", data).map(...'